# Yii mysql server gone away

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Setting up a queue to sit idle to process data as it comes in, from time to time I get the awesome error about the mysql server has gone away. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to gracefully fix this within Yii, when the error is given, I could re-initiate the database connection and continue.

Don't care too much for mysql settings to increase the wait_time as it can help minimize the issue but not solve it.

**Edit**
This may seem funny/sad depending on how you look at it....I added @ symbols to the queries I was running and they were getting caught by a try-catch...I reset the database connection if the error code is within range[2006], otherwise the application returns an error......hopefully this seems like a legitimate answer...

Comment: Are [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+has+gone+away) of any use? This is likely just a MySQL issue, rather than a Yii one.

Comment: @halfer I am forcing the mysql gone away message by restarting the mysql server on purpose to try and have an interceptor on yii to recover from mysql leaving

Comment: what kind of data do you have in mysql , probably you need to put the data in cache in b/w those intervals

Comment: @sakhunzai I have a queue worker that makes a few reads[only when redis keys have expired], then it just writes the data.

Comment: Is the idle time overnight?

Comment: Its not a YII FW problem its a mysql server problem, check mysql ini to solve it

Comment: @Sabbir I was deliberately stopping and starting sql to throw the error to get yii to work with it

Comment: You application scenarios is not clear . if your application relies on MySQL for data why you what to push it into corner intentionally. Is this part of your application business logic to kill the MySQL for a while and do sth and restart it ? please describe the business logic you are trying to implement. Otherwise if you are trying to see what will happen when MySQL is unavailable for your application, you will get errors when you hit a page what relies on db data e.g using model or MySQL queries.

Comment: @sakhunzai My application gets random mysql server gone away errors, rather than me waiting for that to happen, I force the restart so I can debug my code immediately.

Comment: To debug you have to look in to Apache logs(access, error). You will get the idea from where exactly the error is generated.This kind of error could be bcz of bad code/MySQL query/ not enough memory or system resources. Share the logs

Comment: @Brian Putt Is it on hosted on a shared server? Or, contact your service provider. We got similar problem with a service provider and when we moved to AWS same code have not any single issue!

Comment: @Sabbir I ended up catching the error and believe it works fine, I have it retry 2x and if it fails, it exits...Supervisor then restarts the worker and everything resumes just fine

Comment: @BrianPutt happy to hear your problem is solve :)

Answer (score 3):

I search a lot about this problem, this happens in Yii when you use especially Yii Commands. I don't know why Yii create a new connection per each AR if autoConnect is not set to false, that means to reuse a open connections.

```
    'db' => array(
         // Reuse a connections and not exceed the number of connections to got error 2006
        'autoConnect' => false,
         // If you are using a transactions and persistent connections
        'attributes' => array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => FALSE
        )
    ),
```

Comment: great to hear that. where did you found the explaination for it?

Comment: From yii docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.5/CDbConnection#autoConnect-detail

"whether the database connection should be automatically established the component is being initialized. Defaults to true. ..."

I've seen this when i make multiple query through AR filling array structure on __construct of Components. In little words means that when you initialize new components that use AR if is false yii doesn't create new connection with him.

Comment: You must take present that server gone has many reason that happens. The answer here is to reduce use of number of resources in interval of time. But if your query take a lot of data (for example if you have text columns with serialized data or articles) this error happens so in this case you must increase (max_allowed_packet = 256M). More info here is the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: I used the same process, increase max_allowed_packet = 500M, but till today the error happen again

Comment: Maybe you have other problem on top of all reset the connections:

                    Yii::app()->db->setActive(FALSE);
                    Yii::app()->db->setActive(TRUE);

Comment: Yii::app()->db->setActive(FALSE); Yii::app()->db->setActive(TRUE); this 2 lines are great. why don't Yii have some util function for toggle connection. thanks It save me a lot of. due to my simulation of the problem. this should work by catch the exception and do 2 magic code line above, then good to go.

Answer (score 2):

i solved by adding

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M
wait_timeout=3600
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

in my.cnf of mysql